# How and is it possible to split strings when coding a discord bot?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So I'm a newbie with discord.py but I've learnt python in the pass so I'm able to follow along and learn from tutorials pretty easily. I'm trying to create a pretty simple bot to try and get the hang of the language, where if i were to type !give(anything) the bot would reply with "(anything) was given".

Can someone help me with this? Also are there any good introductory sources for discord.py?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find("!give") != -1:
       await message.channel.send_message("A" + message[5:] + ' was given')
```

This was my first code that ^^ was based off of:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find("!givehug") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("**A hug was given**")
    elif message.content.find("!givekiss") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("**A kiss was given**")
```

Comment: To split Strings in python we use `.split()`. In your case you do no want the prefix to be part of the final message. Something like `message.content.split(' ').remove('!command')`. You can find a simple example [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py).

Comment: ohhh thank you for that;
would i set it so that it's (a new variable) = message.content.split(message).remove('!give') then?

I'm sorry if this too much of a bother ;-;

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your current code? What is wrong with it? Are you getting any exceptions (if so, give the full traceback), or just not the output you expect? Can you give details, like an input command that you type, and the incorrect response (and what you expected to get instead)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Cogs instead. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#quick-example

It will be just like that:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    ...

@client.command(pass_context=True, name="givehug")
async def givehug(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send("**A hug was given to {user}**".format(user=user.name)
```

You could also check out this repo https://github.com/ThatMajesticGuy/ShimaRinBot

Comment: thank you for your reply!

I'm not sure if it's just my coding skills or the program I'm using but when i try to use any command prefixes it doesn't work and comes out with
'Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "-(command)" is not found
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "(command)" is not found

and prints the end result twice....is there any way to fix that?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that is not always a good idea using the find function (for example if you create an help command, with the list of all commands, you will get a false positive). Maybe you can check if the first char is your prefix and then replace the command you found:

```py
def give(message):
    str = message.content.split(" ")[0].replace("give", "")
    message.channel.send("**A "+str+" was given**")

// ...
// ... your code ...
// ...

prefix = "!"
if (message.content[0] == prefix):
    command = message.content.split(" ")[0]

    if(command == prefix + "give"):
            // code block
            give(message)
           
    elif(command == prefix + "another-command"):
            // code block
            pass
```

Is a good practice to separate code, therefore if you can use more functions.

Comment: This answer isn't using Python, which is what the questioner is using.

Comment: my bad, i saw async and i started typing lol, im gonna edit

Comment: I put that into my code file where i replaced {} with a ':' & function with def since it would've been invalid syntax, but it still came up with an error saying that the message had no content? Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: have you tried after my refactor? can you copy exactly the message error?

Comment: i haven't written:

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

 maybe you just copy and pasted and therefore python can't find "message"